# SharePoint 2010 web and load testing with VS2012.4: Recorded upload file doesn't add the file to the project

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm for which I have created a Web Performance and Load Test Project in Visual Studio 2012.4 Ultimate.
When adding a web test for uploading a file, the uploaded file is not automatically added to my project after successful recording of the test on my SP 2010 site.

Am I missing some VS configuration settings?

Comment: watch this video and double check if you miss something. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYrQwSrU6xQ

Comment: The video is more about general setup of Web Performance and Load Test. I'm looking into the specific case: a webtest which is uploading a file in a document library But when I try this my recorded web test doesn't add the file in my VS project and than when testing the webtest it fails on missing the file which needs to be uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to manually add the file to your Visual studio project so that it will travel with the test through your source control system.